# Login to a django project using an external python cript

Tags: python, django, urllib2, django-authentication, django-login

I have created a django project that uses login and checks if user is staff in order to execute some views and render some pages. The code works great. I want to create a client program lets say in Gtk that connets to the django project and gets info from db using an api. The api can be simple enough, not to many models on my Django project. I know there r some great apps for creating apis like TasyPie, but I think i need something so much simpler. My question though is this: My plan is to use urllib2 to get the response from a django view

But my question is this. How do i check if user is logged using urllib2. I mean Django has the request.user method. Can i use this outside of Django?Or do i need to always send username and  password with each request, and let django check if the users is authenticated staff etc?

e.g I was thinking something like this
django view

```
def get_some_data(request):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated():
        return some json_data
```

and the urllib2 script

```
data = some_data_to_post_dict
data = urllib.urlencode(data)
req = urllib2.Request('http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_some_data.html')
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

That is the basic logic of my idea. Do i need to put inside the data of my urllib2 script the username and password and check them in every request to the api?

e.g
django view

```
def get_some_data(request):
    if request.method = 'POST':
        username = request['username']
        password = request.['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password) #do i need that in every view of my api's?
        if user_loggedin:
            return json_data
```

urllib2 script

```
data = {'username'='some_username', 'password'='some_password', other_data} #do i have to always include username and password on my data from urllib2 script?
data = urllib.urlencode(data)
req = urllib2.Request('http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_some_data.html')
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could grab and set the session cookie, which is what the browser does when logging you in, however this is exactly the use-case for tastypie and django rest framework. They're both *much* easier to use than what you're planning here (even for small projects).

Comment: I also finoun this http://goo.gl/5mFifa which worked like a charm. You  still recomend tastypie or rest framework right?

Comment: that url doesn't work for me, but yes, those frameworks are easy to install, easy to use, and made for exactly this purpose, by people who've thought about boring things like throttling/caching/etc.

Comment: http://www.forgottenlabs.com/2011/06/how-to-authenticate-in-django-via-urllib2/  i meant this link here.